# Get current, requested URL in Bottle

Tags: templates, bottle

I would like put some block of code in my base template but only `if request.route is '/page'`.

I was trying add some like:

```
% if request.route == "/home":
  <a class="pure-button" id="showWishboneAddForm">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Dodaj tuleję
  </a>
% end
```

But then I got error:
`NameError("name 'request' is not defined",)`

I don't want add `request` argument to all routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple make the request available on all view/templates 's in the following easy* way

```
from bottle import view, request, template, get
from functools import partial
view = partial(view, request=request)
template = partial(template, request=request)    

#now lets use it
@get("/")
@view("mytpl.tpl")
def index():
    return {"msg": "Cool stuff!"}
```

I hope it will do what you need

Comment: Thank you! Additionally I found something like: `SimpleTemplate.defaults["request"] = request`

Comment: You should not do this because this is not thread safe. You could have a page with the wrong "request" variable in the template.

Comment: @AugustinLaville - the `request` object uses `thread.local` so it should be OK.

Comment: I'm sure it's not, do the test.